# What causes a whirlpool to form in a bathtub?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, vortex

I mean, when you have a full bathtub and then let it empty, under what conditions does a whirlpool form?

Could we devise an experiment and measure this effect? When it comes to fluids, I don't know why I can't think of anything to test a hypothesis.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7738/2451 and links therein.

Comment: This question deals with estimating the effect of the Coriolis force: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32/resolving-water-sink-problem . This question deals with why the vortex forms at all: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/why-theres-a-whirl-when-you-drain-the-bathtub . I'll move my answer to the latter question.