# Coriolis effect in the bathroom?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, estimation, vortex, coriolis-effect

I understand that the Coriolis effect is not responsible for the spin effect in the bathroom, but I have never seen a rigorous math prof of this. Where could I find a proof of this? What references could I read to try to proof it? is it very long?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show that the Coriolis effect is irrelevant for the whirl/vortex in the sink/bathtub?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32/)

Answer (score 0):

Who needs a proof? It's an easy experiment: fill your sink, stir it a bit, and note that the drain vortex rotates in the direction you stirred it. Try gentler stirring, and longer wait before you pull the plug. When the visible rotation stops, do you consistently get the same result regardless of how you initially stirred it?